# Volley never returns VolleyError or explains why there is an exception

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonexception

With the Volley libraries, I extended the Request object to implement GSON serialization.  I then extended that new object for how I want to do some of my `PUT` requests.  This is the first object for the GSON serialization:

```
@Override  
protected Response<t> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {  
    try {  
        String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers)); //response may be too large for string?
        t parsedGSON = mGson.fromJson(jsonString, cls);
        Response <t> returnMessage = Response.success(parsedGSON,  
                HttpHeaderParser.parseIgnoreCacheHeaders(response));
        return returnMessage;

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));  
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException je) {
        je.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("GsonRequest", je.getMessage()!=null?je.getMessage():"JsonSyntaxError");
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));  
    }  
}
```

When my network response gets to `Response <t> returnMessage = Response.success(parsedGSON,  HttpHeaderParser.parseIgnoreCacheHeaders(response));` I have populated `<t>` objects with the correct classes I passed in completely serialized with all variables and no errors. Yet for some reason Volley jumps to `} catch (JsonSyntaxException je) {` and I can't reveal the contents of `je` with debugging breakpoints or printing logs. Also in my extended class:

```
 new ErrorListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
```

The `onErrorResponse` is never called (neither is my `onResponse` section either)

So now I have no idea why Volley is catching a JSONException, when serialization was successful, and I have no idea why Volley isn't returning the Error objects

Insight appreciated

Comment: What kind of object are you using for performing the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that any Volley function you extend or override must have

```
    @Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
```

function implemented. The Listener must be initialized in the constructor and have the onResponse method implemented.

Otherwise your network call will never return in the `onResponse` section.

EDIT:
and your extended Request class has to also implement deliverError, along with deliverResponse

```
private final Listener<T> mListener;
private ErrorListener mErrorListener;

@Override
 public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
    mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
}
```

with `ErrorListener` initialized in your constructor

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem this morning. Probably you are not receiving a Json as response, your server is answering with a 200 OK but Volley is waiting for receiving a Json. Than, when it does not receive a Json it generates that error, which has not a HTTP code (because it is not), but is a volley internal error.

You may solve the problem by using the right object (from the volley library) for performing your requests.

If you use a JsonObjectRequest volley needs a JSONObject in the request's body and is aspecting for a JSONObject in the response object.
If you use a JsonArrayRequest volley needs a JSONArray in the request and a JSONArray in the response.
For each different case you need to extend the JsonRequest class for managing the response.

Comment: Hmm, I am extending the Request<t> object. I am not using JsonObjectRequest or JsonArrayRequest. I am using my own extended method from the lower level Request<t> object and adding my own GSON serializing in the response..

Answer (score 1):

For JSON why don't you use own class for answer, for example:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class UserData {
@SerializedName("email")
public String userMail;
@SerializedName("number")
public String number;
@SerializedName("loginName")
public String loginName;
@SerializedName("password")
public String password;
```

}

and then

```
public Request<?> getInformation(String loginName, String password, Response.Listener<UserData> responseListener,
                                         Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

    String url = apiURL;

    Map<String, String> authHeaders = getAuthHeaders(loginName, password);
    authHeaders.put(HEADER_PARAM_INTERFACE_KEY, DPAG_INTERFACE_KEY);
    int method = Request.Method.GET;

    GsonRequest<UserData> request = new GsonRequest<UserData>(
            method,
            url,
            UserData.class,
            authHeaders,
            responseListener,
            errorListener,
            gson);


    return mQueue.add(request);
}
```

plus here the onResponse and on ErrorResponse

```
    Application.get().getApi().getInformation(loginName, password,
            new Response.Listener<UserData>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(UserData data) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                }
            }
    );
```